# ¿Cómo listar las entradas de wordpress que no sea en la página principal?

Tags: php, wordpress

Normalmente cuando entras a un blog se muestran todas las entradas se muestran en la página principal por causa del archivo `index.php`; yo quiero **poner un enlace** en mi `index.php` y que al redireccionar me muestre una lista (con el tipico while) de las entradas que tengo (como si fuese la página principal)

básicamente, es un blog que las entradas no se muestran en el landing, sino que va a tener un enlace (en el `index.php`) que redireccione hacia donde están las entradas.

no se como hacer eso. lo que más se me dificulta es el redireccionamiento, y el archivo que se usa para listarlo ni `single.php` ni el `page.php` me sirven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En ese caso creo que estaríamos hablando de **otra página** diferente de tu página principal que te muestre una lista de entradas.

Te explicaré cómo lo hago yo, de una forma muy sencilla. Si captas esta técnica podrías ahorrarte horas de trabajo en Wordpress.

Para cosas como esta (y otras similares) yo uso mi propio `shortcode`, sin necesidad de plugins ni nada por el estilo.

Imaginemos que creas una página donde se listarán tus últimas entradas, o tus entradas por categoría... o varios tipos de entradas organizadas como quieras.

Llamemos a esa página: `mis-entradas`

La creas, como se crea una página o post en WP y dentro de ella pones esto:

```
[entradas categoria="10"]
```

¡Ya tienes un shortcode! Ahora vamos a recuperarlo.

**En el archivo functions.php, o custom.php o el archivo de personalización que estés usando**:

```
//Recibe en el parámetro `$atts` lo que hay dentro del shortcode 
function entradas_func( $atts ) 
{
    $arr = shortcode_atts( array('categoria' => '0'), $atts );
    if ($arr['categoria']==!'0')
    {
        /*
           Muestra una lista de posts usando el id categoría del shortcode
           Se pueden usar otros criterios,
           se puede cambiar el orden, el campo por el que se ordena, etc
           Todo está explicado en la doc (enlaces al final de la respuesta)
        */
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'offset'=> 1, 'cat' => $current, 'orderby' => post_name, 'order' => ASC );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);  
            $datos.='<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'" rel="bookmark" title="'. get_the_excerpt().'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
        endforeach;
        return $datos.'<br /><br />';
    }
}


/*
   Se crea un shortcode llamado `entradas` 
   que llama a la función `entrandas_func`
   Nótese que el 1er parámetro que se pasa a `add_shortcode` 
   es exactamente el dato puesto a la izquierda de: [entradas categoria="10"]
   y el 2do parámetro es el nombre de la función declarada más arriba
*/

add_shortcode( 'entradas', 'entradas_func' );
```

Espero te sirva.

---

#### Enlaces:

- [The Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)
- [add shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)
- [shortcode atts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts)

**Ejemplo:**

Lo que se muestra en [esta página](http://www.deiverbum.org/evangelios/san-mateo/) es un ejemplo de lo que hace el shortcode de más arriba, poniendo en la página algo como esto:

```
[entradas categoria="70"]
```

He implementado también un pequeño *gadget* que consiste en invocar a `get_the_excerpt()` para usarlo como `title` del enlace. Así, cuando colocas el puntero sobre cualquiera de los enlaces, se usa el contenido que hayas puesto en el `excerpt` al momento de crear la entrada en Wordpress, para mostrar un *tool tip* con ese contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eres un pro!! xD. Lo que si no sé es para qué es el $count.

Comment: Ohhh era porque en un principio quería mostrar un número a la izquierda de cada línea pero al final opté por una etiqueta li, era más un error de novato que otra cosa porque no tiene ninguna utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar un Page Template, te dejo un ejemplo de un framework escrito por mi https://github.com/rogertm/twenty-em/blob/master/page-templates/template-blog-excerpt.php, en este caso el Loop lo hace la funcción [t_em_loop()](https://github.com/rogertm/twenty-em/blob/master/functions.php#L1715). Luego cuando creas la página escoges el Template en el panel Atributos de Página.

Saludos

Comment: Sii este método tambien lo implementé.. muchas gracias...